# Workflows not working after backup and restore to new site collection

Tags: 2013, workflow, backup, restore, app-step

We have site collection with data in it with workflows2013 that have app steps.
Task was to create site collection on another WA with same data as old SC, so we created new site collection and new db and did back up and restore to new SC.

Everything is ok, but workflows 2013. We noticed that site app permissions for workflow are copied from old SC and what ever we tried it did't work.

I found same/similar problem at this [topic](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/SharePoint/Workflow-problem-after-restoring-a-site-collection/td-p/184252) but what helped poster, didn't to us as we did same thing.

Any suggestion how to get new guid indipendant from old SC for workflow app step? Or any suggestion at all how to publish workflows?

**Edit 1:**
What we found out is that in site app permission, for workflow app identifier is id of original site, not the newly created.
Is it possible to change this (the app identifier)?

Comment: I guess you can create new app step permissions manually for your new site and this will resolve your issue. try this once.

Comment: Did already that. Sorry for not writing this down in original post. But as soon as I tried publishing any old or new workflow 2013, additional workflow app permission was added with original site and workflow again notified me with the same error. So I still cant publish workflows.

Comment: So how exactly you are exporting and restoring old workflows in new site collection? Using Visios or WSP or anything else?

Comment: As I wrote, I did backup and than restore whole site collection, WFs are included. I can see them, I can opet them and edit, but I can't publish them. And only 2013, 2010 is ok. I am sure 100% that is because somehow original site collection id is copied.

Answer (score 1):

Backup and Restore for Workflows 2013 is completely different from Sharepoint backup and Restore. It is separate product and requires separate procedure.

Each site is separate scope in WF databases, you need to perform scope restore procedure for Workflow manager.

> The SharePoint 2010 Workflow platform is integrated with SharePoint
>   Server. When you back up SharePoint Server, or the underlying SQL
>   Server databases, you are automatically backing up the SharePoint 2010
>   Workflow platform. To learn more about backup in SharePoint Server
>   2013, see Backup and restore SharePoint 2013.
>
> In contrast, backing up the SharePoint 2013 Workflow platform is a
>   separate operation from backing up SharePoint Server 2013.

REF: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/jj937239(v=office.14)

http://www.wictorwilen.se/workflow-manager-disaster-recovery-and-restore-options-series

http://alstechtips.blogspot.com/2015/01/sharepoint-2013-how-to-restore-workflow.html